# GeoDjango: Order by distance for model that has a ForeignKey relation to another model that has a PointField

Tags: geodjango

Model A has a ForeignKey relation to Model B. Model B has a PointField. Is there a way to order Model A objects by distance from a POINT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that both Model `A` and `B` are using `objects = models.GeoManager()`, the FK field on Model A is named `b`, Model `B` has `PointField` named `point`, and `pnt` is a GEOSGeometry then the following should work:

```
A.objects.distance(pnt, field_name='b__point').order_by('distance')
```

Comment: thanks. i have yet to try this, but it looks promising. is this documented somewhere? i couldn't find it...